# How to convert a number to base 11 in python?

Tags: python, numbers, integer

I'm trying to convert a number to base 11 in python. But it is giving me the wrong output or may be the syntax I'm using is incorrect.

```
print(int('120',11))
```

In http://extraconversion.com, it is saying that base 10 to base 11 conversion of number 120 is **AA**. But the above python statement is giving me output 143. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You're going the opposite direction. `120` in base 11 is `143` in base 10, which is what your code is doing. This behavior is [clearly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int)

Comment: How do I do the conversion then?